# Rails - obfuscate_id errors on find() in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using the obfuscate_id gem ( https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id ).

We obfuscate ID's by inserting one line into the top of each model:

```
obfuscate_id
```

It works great and as expected. My ID's are obfuscated.

However, as part of some logic in my `ApplicationController`, I have some logic to check the current user and each controller has access to these methods as helpers:

```
def current_user

    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]

end
```

However, I get an error:

> **Couldn't find User with id=5164061535**

It doesn't seem to be able to convert the obfuscated ID back to its normal form for a find().

How can I get the controllers to recognise this obfuscation that's made in each model.

My user model is like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # This part obfuscates the user ID
    obfuscate_id

    has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :pins
    has_many :replies, through: :pins

end
```

Any ideas how I can get the `ApplicationController` to recognise this? Doing find() in each controller itself is fine, but as `ApplicationController` doesn't have its own model, it doesn't seem to know of it.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: I don't know of it, but what if you try a custom method in user.rb, like "def self.theuser(uid) \r self.find(uid) \r end" and access like User.theuser(session[:user_id]).

Comment: I get the same error trying your idea above! Seems like it just passes it on to user.rb but ends up at the same problem. Weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, I ended up trying this:

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

And it worked! But, why?

`User.find()` in itself was not working with this gem. So, although it's now working, it concerns me a little as to why exactly.

If anyone could add anything here that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right!  The "find" method is monkey-patched by the obfuscate_id gem... the "find_by" isn't.   We've been assuming that the id stored in session[:user_id] was obfuscated... if you can retrieve the record by "find_by" that means it isn't obfuscated.  We should have inspected the contents of session[:user_id]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Steve. Seems to make a little more sense!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 @current_user ||= User.find(User.deobfuscate_id(session[:user_id])) if session[:user_id]
```

Comment: (although looking at the gem, they did monkey-patch :find so I don't understand why it doesn't work as you coded it)

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the same error but a different ID shown: Couldn't find User with id=8063132118

Comment: If you run rails console ("rails c") and type "User.deobfuscate_id(5164061535)" what do you see returned?

Comment: If I run that command in Rails Console, I get: => "2566236117". I would have expected something like "50" - which is what the ID was originally. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: ...I managed to discover a work-around. See my answer - any ideas?